# Getting error org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Hibernate and spring i have used spring mvc for the web portal,
but once i am triggering the service from the POSTMAN the data is getting stored at backed but once i am triggering the same service from the front end, for the first time it is successful but the second time i am getting the below error.

```
   Hibernate: insert into tip_DailyReport (NoOfRequestClosed, NoOfRequestCreated, NoOfRequestInProgress, NoOfRequestReOpened, NoOfRequestServiced, TimeStamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2017-11-19 09:48:59 ERROR AssertionFailure:50 - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.abnamro.tdm.tip.entity.DailyReport entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.abnamro.tdm.tip.entity.DailyReport entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1191)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1675)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    at com.abnamro.tdm.tip.dataDao.DailyReportDataDaoImpl.getDailyReportList(DailyReportDataDaoImpl.java:46)
    at com.abnamro.tdm.tip.services.DailyReportServicesImpl.getDailyReportList(DailyReportServicesImpl.java:28)
    at com.abnamro.tdm.tip.controller.DailyReportController.getDailyReport(DailyReportController.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tip_DailyReport")
public class DailyReport implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "TimeStamp")
    private String timeStamp;
    `
```

DataDaoImpl Class:

```
public boolean addDailyReport(DailyReport dailyReport) throws Exception {

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    //System.out.println(dailyReport.getId());
    session.save(dailyReport);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you trying to insert a certain field of **DailyReport** to **NOT NUll** column in the database, try to place your code inside **try/catch** block to take the real exception.

Comment: Hi Ibrahim ,Thanks for the response, I have tried try and catch as well but getting the same error. try{
    session.save(dailyReport);
    tx.commit();
    } catch(Exception ex){
     throw ex;
    } finally{
     session.close();
    }